# Convert a data type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to select a data range in a data set that I converted.  Here is what I have, but not sure what I'm missign:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("2020_Transactions_v03.txt", delimiter="|")
df1["Transaction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Transaction Date"])
start_date = '2020-03-01'
end_date = '2020-04-01'
mask = (df1['Transaction Date'] > start_date) & (df1("Transaction Date") <= end_date)
print(df1.loc[mask])
```

This isn't really working as I expected (filtering only the dates that I needed to convert the data type in the first place).  Any ideas on how to select only the dates within the mask?

Comment: `df1["Transaction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Transaction Date"]); df1 = df1.set_index(convert_trans_date)` you are not setting your index inplace or to a variable

Comment: `df.set_index("Transaction Date", drop=False)` ... `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`